# Where the heck should Paint reside in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-paint

Our sysadmin folks did some patches and somehow uninstalled Paint.  (They uninstalled Media Player too.)  Didn't even know that they did it until I told them.  ~~shrug~~

Anyway, where should Paint be located?  Maybe the installer will be there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be located in C:\Windows\system32

To install windows software, you need to go to add/removes program -> add/removes windows component.

Comment: OK, went there, but it shut down when it couldn't find Freecell.  They've stripped games off of our computers.

I remember when the guy re-enabled Media Player he launched the installer from Windows Explorer.

Comment: If you are at work, they must have desactivated those aoftware, you will not be able reinstall these in any way.

Comment: Found the executable right in Windows\system32.  Don't know what the heck they're doing that breaks all of the shortcuts, though.  Hehe.  I'll vote up when I get enough rep. ;)

Comment: @JW. You might want to use GIMP and VNC viewer as they work far better than their software that they replace and they are widely used and open source.

Answer (score 1):

**Insert the XP Installation disk** and then:

1. Go to the *Start Menu*
2. Click *Control Panel*
3. Double-click *Add/Remove Programs*
4. Click *Add/Remove Windows Components*
   on the left-hand side

Paint is under *Accessories and Utilities*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Please see comment on Livinloud's answer.  Any way around this?

Comment: I can see it's already solved. That's the way! :)